# end_unique algorithm, element disappear

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void elimdups(vector<string>& words) {
    sort(words.begin(), words.end());
    for(auto a : words)
    {
        cout << a << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    auto end_unique = unique(words.begin(), words.end());
    for (auto a : words)
    {
        cout << a << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    words.erase(end_unique, words.end());
    for (auto a : words)
    {
        cout << a << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


int main()
{
    vector<string> kim = { "love", "peace", "horrible", "love", "peace", "hi", "hi" };
    elimdups(kim);

    return 0;
}
```

--
result:

```
hi hi horrible love love peace peace

hi horrible love peace love  peace

hi horrible love peace
```

end_unique algorithm do not delete elements.
but on the second cout operation, "hi" disappear.
why "hi" disappear on the second line?

Comment: The `hi` disappeared since it was overwritten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
auto end_unique = unique(words.begin(), words.end()); 
for (auto a : words)
//...
```

Any items from `[end_unique, words.end())` have unspecified values after the call to `std::unique`.  That's why the output in the "erased" range seems strange.

If you want to preserve the "erased" words and keep the relative order,  [std::stable_partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) with the [appropriate lambda](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1326b97a8c4cc465) that checks duplicates could have been done.